# How do I customise the default 404 response for a URL not found error using Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, rest, http-status-code-404, django-rest-framework

I want to know how to display an error page like this when there is a 404 error for a not-found resource on my Django Rest Framework API:

```
{
    'detail': 'The resource was not found'
}
```

I can't find out how to do this, because most of the tutorial is just assuming that you are setting up a specific URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django Rest Framework overrides Django Http404 in [exception_handler](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/views.py) so you need to write your own exception.  Example:

```
class NotFound(APIException):
    status_code = status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND
    default_detail = 'The resource was not found.'

    def __init__(self, detail=None):
        self.detail = detail or self.default_detail
```